# Phone battery use searching for a signal

Tags: iphone, battery

I just got hi speed internet and turned on wi-if calling on my iPhone 6 since I have poor signal at home. Also just installed a signal extender(booster)from Verizon, which increased my signal to full strength. 
Since I don't need both I was going to send back the $160. Extender to Verizon, but would my phone then be searching for a better signal even though its on wifi calling and using more battery life?

Comment: Verizon ought to give you the booster for free (some carriers at least used to, I’m not in that industry anymore tho and don’t know what current carrier thought is)... tell them you’ll need to change providers if they can’t provide signal to your home.

Answer (score 1):

It might. [This questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278940/myth-need-to-be-solved-will-the-battery-drain-faster-in-places-with-poor-wifi-s) shows several factors there are to battery loss, including the cell reception, but that Wifi can help reduce that. I would recommend following his 5 day test procedure before returning the signal extender.